# Chebyshev's inequality and quadratic function

Tags: probability, approximation

I am trying to use Chebyshev's inequality in order to find sample sizes $n$ such that some condition is met with probability $p$ or larger. That is, find $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n > k) \geq p$ $(p \in (0,1), k > 0)$ .

Subtracting from both sides, I get that $\mathbb{P}(X_n > k) = \mathbb{P}(X_n - \mathbb{E}(X_n) > k - \mathbb{E}(X_n))$.

Also, $\mathbb{P}(X_n > k) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq k)$.

So, using Chebyshev's inequality, I end up with:
 $\mathbb{P}(X_n > k) \geq \mathbb{P}(|X_n - \mathbb{E}(X_n)| > k - \mathbb{E}(X_n)) \geq \displaystyle\frac{V(X_n)}{(k - \mathbb{E}(X_n))^2}$.

Now, after doing that in some exercises, I am getting an inequality consisting of a quadratic function and the constant $0$, where the function has $a > 0$ and two positive roots.

If I take that inequality literally, it says that the original probability bound can be satisfied with small values of $n$ (even $n=0$!), which does not make much sense.

Therefore there must be some other equation or hypothesis to take into account before finding a correct bound for $n$. What is that extra piece of information am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not quite sure your question would really make sense without without having a greater sense of how $X_n$ behaves with $n$, but both inequalities in the sentence starting "So,..." are incorrect since 1.$\{X > k\} \subset \{|X - \mu| > k - \mu\}$, and 2. the form of [Chebychev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_statement). In fact, C.'s I. talks about upper bounds on the tail of the distribution, and I doubt you can pull results of the form $P(X > k) \ge p$ from it in general.

Comment: In the simpler cases I was doing, $X_n$ is the sum of positive random variables. The form of the inequality I'm using can be derived from the definition.

Comment: Well, the argument for 1. definitely stands. 2 - I may be missing something obvious, but again, far as I recall, you can only get lower bounds for bounded supports from C.'s I. I'll have a scribble to try and see. Anyway, in case you're certain there's no mistake, perhaps a clarification on the sentence "Now..." would help. Do you mean that $P(X_n > k) \ge a_n k^2 + b_n k$ or something else?

Comment: All this is kind of confusing. At that point I get an inequality like $an^2 + bn + c \geq 0$ or $an^2 + bn + c \leq 0$ from which values of $n$ should be extracted for the answer.

Comment: I am not sure what the $X_n$ are. That said, you seem to want to show (first paragraph) that some tail probability is big if $n$ is large enough. Out of Chebyshev, you can only expect to show that some tail probability is **small**.